# Error con atributo extra al agrupar items por medio de categorias

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

**categorias**

```
   |------|--------|
   |  id  |  name  |
   |------|--------|
   |  1   |   c1   |
   |------|--------|
   |  2   |   c2   |
   |------|--------|
   |  3   |   c3   |
   |------|--------|
```

**items**

```
   |------|---------|--------|-------------|
   |  id  |  catid  |  name  | modified_by |
   |------|---------|--------|-------------|
   |   1  |    1    |   i1   |    juan     |
   |------|---------|--------|-------------|
   |   2  |    1    |   i2   |    pedro    |
   |------|---------|--------|-------------|
   |   3  |    2    |   i3   |    pedro    |
   |------|---------|--------|-------------|
   |   4  |    2    |   i4   |    josé     |
   |------|---------|--------|-------------|
   |   5  |    3    |   i5   |    pedro    |
   |------|---------|--------|-------------|
```

Y Ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(i.id) AS countid 
FROM categories AS c 
INNER JOIN items AS i ON i.catid = c.id 
WHERE c.id IN (1,2,3) GROUP BY i.catid
```

Lo que quiero es agrupar la cantidad de ID's que tiene cada categoria al hacer el count de los items en esa categoria, pero me marca el siguiente error

> #1055 - Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.i.modified_by' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Si quito el atributo `modified_by` en el **select** el error desaparece pero deseo mantenerlo. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: que tiene ese atributo? cual es la logica para traerlo?

Comment: Lo puse como ejemplo, en realidad son más campos, los utilizo para desplegarlos al usuario en una tabla

Comment: entonces para saber como traerlos, vamos a necesitar saber las claves de las tablas.. y cual de todos los campos necesitas.. o sea.. si hay un group, quiere decir que esos campos tienen distintos valores... cual de todos queres???

Comment: Creo que ya me diste una pista del problema. El error se da por que los atributos extra que quiero traer tienen valores distintos y al ponerlos en el group by no se pueden mostrar ¿verdad?

Comment: El error mismo te lo dice, o agrupas por el campo o le difinis una funcion de agregacion al campo. Todos esos campos extra, si tiene  muchos valores, deberias saber cual de ellos mostrar... maximo? Minimo?

Comment: Mi intención era contar el numero de items en cada categoria y en base a eso mostrar quién lo modificó en la misma consulta, pero por lo que me has dicho, me dí cuenta que eso no se puede porque la columna modified_by puede tener varios resultados para una misma fila. Creo que la respuesta a mi pregunta es hacer dos consultas separadas

Comment: Claro. en este momento tu consulta no tiene respuesta, porque si mostraras todo en una sola fila, cual seria lo que vas a mostrar en las otras columnas? bajo que logica? nop. no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como te indican, el error concreto es resultado de no añadir todos los campos de la selección en la agrupación. Unicamente las [funciones de agregado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql) no lo necesitarán.

Procura no añadir excesivos campos en la clausula GROUP BY, puedes crear la agrupación en una vista nueva o tabla temporal y a partir de ella realizar LEFT JOIN con el resto de valores que necesites.